# Convert tensor list to tensor of tensors

Tags: python, list, pytorch

I have a variable `a` which is a bunch of tensors like this:

```
[tensor([0.0014, 0.0021, 0.0015, 0.0007, 0.0012, 0.0024, 0.0021, 0.0019, 0.0010,
        0.0010])]
[tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]

....
```

And when I want to do this as part of my code:

```
x = torch.tensor(a, dtype=torch.float)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

Which I assumed that maybe I need to convert each tensor in `a` like this:

```
[tensor([[0.0014], [0.0021], [0.0015], [0.0007], [0.0012], [0.0024], [0.0021], [0.0019], [0.0010],
        [0.0010]])]
[tensor([[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]])]
```

Is what I think right? or what I need exactly to avoid the error above?

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

In pytorch you can use the view() method to reshape the tensor.
Use this code to be precise:

`t2 = t1.view(t1.shape[0],-1)` where t1 is the tensor to be reshaped.

**Working code:**

```
t1 = torch.Tensor([1.6455e-04, 1.2067e-04, 4.3461e-04, 2.0265e-04, 1.4014e-04, 2.0691e-04,
        1.2612e-04, 9.2561e-05, 9.4662e-05, 7.3938e-05])

tensor_lst = []
tensor_lst.append(t1)

res_t = [] #reshaped tensor
for i in range(len(lst)):
    res_t.append(lst[i].view(lst[i].shape[0],-1))

print(res_t)
```

Comment: I got this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'view' @Ashish Johnson

Comment: This is because you are using the view method on the list, you have to access the tensor inside the list and then use .view() method. If you can share the code I will make correction.

Comment: I edit/update the question with the code that causes this error from the beginning, thanks in advance @Ashish Johnson

Comment: @LamaMo After you made the changes it seems that You have a 2D list of tensors, and why are you doing this operation ```x = torch.tensor(a, dtype=torch.float)``` when you already have a list of floating tensors in 'a' ? Please reformulate the question. Also show me the initialization of variable 'a'

Answer (score -1):

Easy, just reshape it. Assuming that your tensor/tensors are stored in a list called `tlist`:

```
tlist = [t.reshape(-1,1) for t in tlist]
```

Comment: I got this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'